# Ice lined refrigerator(ILR)

Tags: states-of-matter, liquid-state

Disclaimer: An ILR has cabinet temperature of +2 to +8 °C and at the same time they do have lining of water containers(ice tubes), fitted all around the walls and held in place by a frame. When it is functioning ,the water in the walls freezes and this cools the cabinet.

My question is how is it possible to have ice walls but the temperatures of inside them at more than 0°C , at normal pressure?

Comment: How can you have ice cubes in your drink, yet the drink is above freezing?

Comment: After sometime ice cubes will get heat and convert into liquid, but in case of ILR there is continuous supply of energy to maintain wall at freezing temperatures but wouldn't that eventually let cooling of inside too to freezing temperatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some heat leaks between the tubes, the ice cannot completely surround the interior or, as you suspected, equilibrium would be reached. ILRs are used to store medical products that require constant refrigeration. The ice tubes provide a longer cold holdover time, compared to standard refrigerators, in case of power failure, so they are safer for heat sensitive vaccines and such.